# How can I read this parameters inside my software? (c#)

Tags: c#

I have created a shortcut of my .exe file.
I want add  to '.exe' extra parameters.(on shortcut: Target attribute)
**Example**
Target:
"C:\Documents and Settings\dezigo\My Documents\c# programm\DirectoryScanner\DirectoryScanner\DirectoryScanner\bin\Debug\DirectoryScanner.exe" + extra parrams(like a method=1)

**How can I read this parameters inside my software? (c#)**
Then ,when starting .exe  
check

```
if(method == 1)
{
 //do something
}
else
{
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Environment.CommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) property to get the command line that has been passed when running the executable and parse it to obtain the parameters. Arguments will also be passed in the `Main` method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The args array will contain the arguments passed at the command line
        // For example if the executable has been launched like: 
        // "DirectoryScanner.exe method=1"
        // args[0] will contain "method=1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use args variable passed into main function.

Here You will find details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251798.aspx